# How to get the directory information in the workspace of Light Table?

Tags: lighttable

[image]

Opening recent workspace shows the directories and files that I opened before, then how to get the directory location of them? I tried right click, but I see no information.

I expect something like this from Code Runner.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I'm a member of the open source Light Table team.]

Light Table doesn't provide that info as you expect.

I agree that that would be a really useful feature, especially when you have multiple directories with the same name in different paths.

Maybe a tooltip when you hover over a directory that shows the full path would be the minimal change that would be helpful.

If you're willing to contribute, or know someone that is, feel free to create [new issues in the GitHub repo](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/new) for each of the Code Runner features you'd like to be implemented. Otherwise, add them to [the feature wishlist wiki page](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/wiki/Feature-wishlist).

These features could be implemented as plugins but I think some of them might arguably be fine implemented in the core app code. Pull requests welcome!